# For people with spare Raspberry Pis what is the easiest way to get a full node running?

Tags: full-node, raspberry-pi

I got some raspberry pi 3s kicking around and would like to put them to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your pi 3, just grab the ARMv7 binaries. https://getmonero.org/downloads/
They'll work for pi 2 as well. If anyone is trying to run a node on pi 1 or pi zero, I can upload ARMv6 binaries but I believe the plan is to drop support for these ARMv6 devices soon.

ARMv6 binaries now available: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/543euo/monero_unofficial_arm_builds/

Also ARMv8 binaries for boxes running 64bit OS. This excludes raspberry pi 3, which only ships with a 32bit OS, and doesn't support ARMv8 crypto instructions.

Comment: I upvoted this, however, Since I have less than 15 positive reputation it did not change the public record :(. Thank you so much for this information! I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 B and have found it to be extremely handy for things of this nature! I will now be running more crypto nodes from different connections at a very cheap price! Much love StackExchange... You finally won me over and I made an account to post this thank you note! P.S. If you're not invested into Monero... You should be!

Answer (score 4):

Rasbian is out because its libboost-all-dev is only version 1.55 (1.58 is required to build). I don't have an rpi3 with Arch Linux on it to test on right now, but that would probably be your best bet since it is a rolling release distro.